# django redirect if user not authenticated within post method of ListView class

Tags: django, django-views

I am relatively new to django, and CBVs and I am trying to figureout how to redirect a user if the user is not authenticated within a `post` method of a `ListView` class. So, the code looks as follows:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

class MyListView(ListView):

    def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
             print "user NOT authenticated"
             return render(request, '/site_templates/home.html')
                         # does not redirect #
        else:
             print "user IS authenticated"
                         # do some stuff: this part works just fine #
```

When I try this, and when user is not authenticated, the code does not seem to redirect me to the template I require. Not sure what I am missing.

Would it be possible to redirect the user here to a TemplateView?
Any help would be great.

Comment: What does it do instead? Does the `user NOT authenticated` text get printed to the console?

Comment: yes `user NOT authenticated` prints and then nothing happens i.e it does not redirect for some reason. All I am looking for is to redirect the user to a TemplateView here

Comment: Is using `HttpResponseRedirect()` not working for you?

Comment: On firebug when I do `HttpResponseRedirect('/myview/')` I see status 200, but the page has not changed for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

if not request.user.is_authenticated():
  return HttpResponseRedirect('desired URL')
```

It's important to emphasize the **return** before the HttpResponseRedirect object.